# Import user object data into header component

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to toggle navigation layout depending if a user is logged in or not.

I've finally managed to obtain user information in +page.svelte .
In this page I also import my Header component so I can easily reuse my header component.

But now my dataobject returns undefined when I want to import the data inside my header component.
Take a look at my +page.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
// @ts-nocheck
    import Header from '/src/components/Header.svelte';
    import Footer from '/src/components/Footer.svelte';
    import Sponsors from '/src/components/Sponsors.svelte';
    import Image from '/src/components/Image.svelte';
    import type { PageData } from './$types';
    export let data: PageData;
    let innerWidth = 0;
</script>

<Header />

<p>{data.email}</p>
<!-- The p tag above shows the email of the logged in user -->
```

But at my header component:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Logo from "./Logo.svelte"
    import type { PageData } from "../routes/$types";
    export let data: PageData;
</script>

<header>
    <div class="header-container">
        <Logo width=120px/>
        <div class="navigation">
            <p>{ data.email }</p>
            <!-- The p-tag above returns undefined -->
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I'm probably making a logical error but it's quite hard to understand.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the page gets passed the `data` property automatically by the framework, right now `Header` is not passed anything.

You either have to forward the data:

```html
<Header {data} />
```

Or use the [`page` store](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-stores-page) inside `Header`, that also contains the data.

Comment: Thanks! What do you recommend?

Comment: Not sure. Would probably integrate the contents of the component into some [layout](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout) and those already get passed `data` of their own (user info would also be loaded in the associated [`+layout.server.js` file](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout-layout-server-js)).